# Is there a way to use rsync without password/key when accounts share same uid/gid/password on both ends?

Tags: ssh, rsync

Assuming a user has the same UID/GID/password on both source and destination servers, is there a way to use rsync without the need to provide a password or a ssh key?

Would there be any security issue in doing so?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `rsnyc` with `fuse/sshfs`, a mounted folder you can simple rsync without a password or a key because the folder is mounted on your system/userspace.

If you work with `rysnc` or `scp`, and don't want to use a password you need to do changes in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote machine on `PermitEmptyPasswords yes`, but that is a security risk!

You can do it once with:
`PermitEmptyPasswords yes`

or with `Match User` and `AllowUsers` like

```
AllowUsers [USER-NAME]@[IP]

Match User [USER-NAME]
  PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

So this will affect only the current user

Check this post, how to rsync from **remote to host** and from **host to remote**

[Copying files using rsync from remote server to local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9090859/15125291)

My tip for you:

Use always a key you can generate a key without a password and use this settings to:

```
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
UsePAM no # this is up to you
```